# Find string in buffer

Tags: c, string, sizeof, strlen

This function browse through the strings added into the buffer and search for the specified field. If the field is found in the buffer, the pointer to the assigned content is returned. If the specified field is not found inside the buffer a pointer to a "?" string is delivered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[256] = "ID=1234 Name=Manavendra Nath Manav Age=30";

const char * get_info (const char *name)
{
    unsigned   nl;
    const char *p, *e;

    if(name!=NULL)
    {
        nl = strlen(name);
        for (p = buf, e = p + strlen(buf) ; p < e && p[0] ; p += strlen(p) + 1) {
            printf("p = %s\tname = %s\te = %s\n", p, name, e);
            if (strncmp (p, name, nl) == 0 && p[nl] == '=')
                return (p + nl + 1);
        }
    }
    return "?";
}

int main()
{
    printf("strlen(buf) = %d\n", strlen(buf));
    printf("%s\n", get_info("Nath"));
    return 0;
}
```

After execution, I am always getting `?` as output, what is wrong with the code? On a second note, would it be advisable to replace `strlen` with `sizeof` in the above code? `sizeof(buf)` returns `256`.

```
manav@os-team:~/programs/test$ ./a.out
strlen(buf) = 21
p = Manavendra Nath Manav       name = Nath     e =
?
```

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't updated about `p[nl] == '='` before. If the buffer is like
`char buf[256] = "ID=1234 Name=Manavendra Nath Manav Age=30";`
then
`get_info("Name")` should return `Manavendra Nath Manav`.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you're just trying to write [strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr), but this isn't what your code does. Could you show what you _want_ the result to be?

Comment: are you allowed to use C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` inside the loop can only execute if `p[nl]` equals `'='`:

```
        if (strncmp (p, name, nl) == 0 && p[nl] == '=')
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, there are no `'='` in your string, so it's the final `return "?"` that always gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer to your question but the logic looks pretty complex. Can't you **substr()** to solve the problem. Moreover 1 mistake I could find  in **if (strncmp (p, name, nl) == 0 && p[nl] == '=')** is **p[nl] == '='** will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the behaviour you're looking for:

```
#include <string>

const char * get_info_2(const char * name){
  std::string str_1(buf);
  std::string str_2(name);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str_1.size() - str_2.size(); ++i){
    if (str_1.substr(i,str_2.size()).compare(str_2) == 0){
      return str_1.substr(i,str_2.size()).c_str();
    }
  }
  return "?";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing your own code for something as common as string matching? The STL has several ways to do this, the simplest being to use `std::string`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

char buf[256] = "Manavendra Nath Manav";
char sub[256] = "Nath";

int main()
{
    std::string bufs(buf);
    std::string subs(sub);

    auto pos = bufs.find(sub);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << bufs.substr(pos, subs.length()) << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "?\n";
}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4hgoW8%2414)

Comment: @Claptrap the original post was tagged C++, someone else removed that.